# How to fix "unresolved external" linker error for System::Set in a C++Builder design-time package?

Tags: linker-errors, c++builder

I'm using C++ Builder 11.3 patch 1.

I have a set of components, all written in C++ and no Delphi code. The components are split into run-time and design-time packages. The run-time package builds without error, but I get this error when I try to build the design-time package:

> [ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::Set<Designintf::TPropertyAttribute, 0, 14>::Set<Designintf::TPropertyAttribute, 0, 14>()' referenced from H:\MyComponents\WIN32\DEBUG\DESIGNTIME.OBJ

I have followed the advice on [Creating or Extending a Package to Use the Tools API](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Creating_or_Extending_a_Package_to_Use_the_Tools_API) and `designide.bpi` is in the `requires` section.

Are there other packages I need to add to fix this?

Comment: That is very odd, because `System::Set` is an inline class implemented wholly in `sysset.h`, so there shouldn't be any external references to its methods that been to be resolved.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Agreed. On my dev PC at work, it all builds properly. But on my home PC it's got this error. I will compare the two setups tomorrow - they should be identical... This may be an issue for Embarcadero support, I guess.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment - it also fails on my work PC. I rarely build the design time BPL as the components are stable... I'll raise a case with Embarcadero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarcadero reports that this is a known bug, scheduled to be fixed in the next major release.

Thankfully, the workaround is simple.

Add this line to the unit that registers the components:

```
TPropertyAttributes foo; //or any name
```

It just needs to be a global variable.